# ¿Como puede generar Controles desde otro proyecto o solucion?

Tags: c#, wpf

Básicamente tengo 3 soluciones (Data, Logic, UI) pero si quiero gestionar que controles se agregan dinámicamente a mi formulario desde Logic me da un error al intentar pasar la librería System.Windows.Form y no puedo crear por ejemplo un Grid o un Label. ¿Qué puedo hacer? ¿Es buena o mala practica hacer esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear controles de formularios necesitas hacerlo en una librería de winforms

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Respondiendo a la pregunta de buenas/malas practicas...

Yo creo que deberías dejar que cada capa haga su trabajo, es decir:

-La capa de datos se encarga de conectarse y hacer consultas a la base de datos

-luego la capa lógica se encarga de las reglas de negocios ya sea como por ejemplo el saldo de la cuenta bancaria no puede ser cero a menos que haga algún préstamo y así. Al principio la capa lógica/business puede ser un pasa manos pero luego se va construyendo y es totalmente normal.

-Por último tienes la capa de presentación/UI donde aquí deberías crear objetos Control dinámicamente y personalizarlos. El flujo seria que la UI llama a la capa lógica, la capa lógica llama a la capa de datos y este devuelve la información solicitada.
También recordar que no se puede mostrar información sensible de datos a la capa de presentación, como tampoco mostrar los errores con detalles, esto a fines de buenas prácticas.